# Convert float to int not loosing information of original values

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I would need to transform float to int. However, I would like to not loose any information while converting it. The values (from a dataframe column used a y in modeling build) that I am taking into account are as follows:

```
-1.0    
 0.0     
 9.0      
-0.5  
 1.5
 1.5    
 ...
```

If I convert them into int directly, I might get -0.5 as 0 or -1, so I will loose some information.

I need to convert the values above to int because I need to pass them to fit a model `model.fit(X, y)`. Any format that could allow me to pass these values in the fit function (the above column is meant y column)?

Code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
X = df[['Col1','Col2']].apply(le.fit_transform)
X_transformed=np.concatenate(((X[['Col1']]),(X[['Col2']])), axis=1)

y=df['Label'].values

scaler=MinMaxScaler()
X_scaled=scaler.fit_transform(X_transformed)

model_LS = LabelSpreading(kernel='knn', 
                          gamma=70,          
                          alpha=0.5, 
                          max_iter=30,
                          tol=0.001,
                          n_jobs=-1, 
                         )


LS=model_LS.fit(X_scaled, y)
```

Data:

```
Col1         Col2     Label
Cust1        Cust2     1.0
Cust1        Cust4     1.0
Cust4        Cust5     -1.5
Cust12       Cust6     9.0
```

The error that I am getting running the above code is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-174-14429cc07d75> in <module>
      2 
----> 3 LS=model_LS.fit(X_scaled, y)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/semi_supervised/_label_propagation.py in fit(self, X, y)
    228         X, y = self._validate_data(X, y)
    229         self.X_ = X
--> 230         check_classification_targets(y)
    231 
    232         # actual graph construction (implementations should override this)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py in check_classification_targets(y)
    181     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput',
    182                       'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:
--> 183         raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
    184 
    185 

ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

Comment: You cannot convert 0.5 into int without loosing some info except if you multiply all the value by 10 before. model works with float, this should works. Moreover labelencoder is for target encoding, not feature encoding. le.fit_transform(y). If label  is continuous you should use a regression model.

Comment: you could change the units. For example if you only use a 1 decimal you could multiply all `*10` and then at the end when you need decimals again divide `/10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiply your values to remove the decimal part:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Label': [1.0, -1.3, 0.75, 9.0, 7.8236]})
decimals = df['Label'].astype(str).str.split('.').str[1].str.len().max()

df['y'] = df['Label'].mul(float(f"1e{decimals}")).astype(int)
print(df)

# Output:
    Label      y
0  1.0000  10000
1 -1.3000 -13000
2  0.7500   7500
3  9.0000  90000
4  7.8236  78236
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'y':[-1.0, 0.0 , 9.0, -0.5, 1.5 , 1.5]})

le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(df['y'])
df['y'] = le.transform(df['y'])
print(df)
```

`OUTPUT`

```
   y
0  0
1  2
2  4
3  1
4  3
5  3
```

Comment: quick question: `df` would be the dataset including the original `Label` column, right? I mean `df['y']` would be `df['Label']`

Comment: Yes exactly....